# pass hidden field in action class

Tags: struts2

```
<s:iterator value="categoryList">
  <s:url id="category" action="/editProduct.action"/>
  <s:a href="%{category}">
    <s:property value="name"/>
  </s:a>
  <s:hidden name = "categoryId"  id = "categoryId" value = "<s:property value='name'/" />
</s:iterator
```

Problem:

I have a list of categories which are click able. Every category has a unique ID. Problem is that when user click on the category from list then  categoryId will pass in editProduct action class
I am searching its solution from two days please help me and define the complete solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't nest JSP tags like that.

```
<s:hidden name="categoryId"  id="categoryId" value="%{name}"/>
```

This, however, makes no sense--if it's not a form, why would you put the `categoryId` into a hidden form field? You're not submitting a form, you're clicking a link.

Put the `categoryId` into the URL as a parameter.

```
<s:url id="category" action="/editProduct.action">
    <s:param name="categoryId" value="%{name}"/>
</s:url>
```

Note that unless "name" is actually something very ID-like, it's probably a bad idea to use it as a primary key.

You may want to go over some HTML and web app basics before proceeding too much further; it will save you time in the long run.

Comment: Dave, tell me the procedure to send this (id) in action class

Comment: i will use javaScript. tell me how i send data from javascript using GET & POST method

Comment: @ZubairIdrees Why would you use JavaScript if you're trying to go to an edit page? And how would you use a GET *and* a POST method?

Comment: how i Put the categoryId into the URL as a parameter

Comment: Dave please tell me how i put the categoryId of that category that is clicked by user from a list of categories

Comment: @ZubairIdrees You need to be more specific. As shown, you're creating a list of URLs to `editAction`, with a `categoryId` parameter. If that's not what you want, edit your question.

Comment: Basically we have a list of categories, when user click on the category then the id of category will go in backhand and take the product of that category

Comment: What's a "list of categories"? A select? An unordered list? What do you mean, "take the product of that category"? Edit your question, or create a new one.

Comment: anchor tag and unordered list

Comment: Then I've answered your question.